# Table or view not found with registerTempTable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I run the following on pyspark shell:

```
>>> data = spark.read.csv("annotations_000", header=False, mode="DROPMALFORMED", schema=schema)
>>> data.show(3)
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+
|   item_id|           review_id|                text|   aspect|sentiment|comments| annotation_round|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+
|9999900031|9999900031/custom...|Just came back to...|breakfast|        3|    null|ASE_OpeNER_round2|
|9999900031|9999900031/custom...|Just came back to...|    staff|        3|    null|ASE_OpeNER_round2|
|9999900031|9999900031/custom...|The hotel was loc...|    noise|        2|    null|ASE_OpeNER_round2|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----------------+
>>> data.registerTempTable("temp")
>>> df = sqlContext.sql("select first(item_id), review_id, first(text), concat_ws(';', collect_list(aspect)) as aspect from temp group by review_id")
>>> df.show(3)
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|first(item_id, false)|           review_id|  first(text, false)|              aspect|
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|               100012|100012/tripadviso...|We stayed here la...|          staff;room| 
|               100013|100013/tripadviso...|We stayed for two...|           breakfast|
|               100031|100031/tripadviso...|We stayed two nig...|noise;breakfast;room|
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

and it works perfectly with the shell sqlContext variable.

When I write it as a script:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="AspectDetector")
spark = SparkSession(sc)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
data.registerTempTable("temp")
df = sqlContext.sql("select first(item_id), review_id, first(text), concat_ws(';', collect_list(aspect)) as aspect from temp group by review_id")
```

and run it I get the following:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Table or view not found: temp;
>   line 1 pos 99'

How is that possible? Am I doing something wrong on the instatiation of sqlContext?

Comment: Initialize it with Hive Context

Answer (score 5):

First you will want to initialize spark with Hive support, for example:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("yarn") \
    .appName("AspectDetector") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
```

But instead of using `sqlContext.sql()`, you will want to use `spark.sql()` to run your query.

I found this confusing as well but I think it is because when you do the `data.registerTempTable("temp")` you are actually in the spark context instead of the sqlContext context. If you want to query a hive table, you should still use `sqlContext.sql()`.